# Java DatagramPacket, how do I separate it?

Tags: java, datagram

So I've currently got a DatagramPacket which gets sent from my client to server.
However I'd like to know how I can separate the data into multiple values.

I.E, lets say I want to send two variables, x and y, and then I want to receive them as two variables on the server-side. How would I do this?

```
int x = 5;
int y = 10;

//Send data to server using a pipe | as a delimiter
byte[] data = Integer.toString(x) + "|" + Integer.toString(y).getBytes();
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, host, port);

...

//Receive data from client
packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[PACKETSIZE], PACKETSIZE);

//Receive a packet (blocking)
socket.receive(packet);

int x = packetSeparate(packet, "an integer");
int y = packetSeparate(packet, "an integer");
```

In other words, on the server side after I've sent the string as a byte array from the client, how would I be able to say:
"integer x is the first integer from the byte array known as: packet.getData()".

```
int x = packet.getData().getAnInteger();
int y = packet.getData().getAnInteger();
```

Also, would it be efficient say, for a networking game, to send a string as bytes?
Or would it be better to convert each individual item into their own bytes and append it to the byte array?

Answer (score 0):

An integer is 4 bytes long, so read 4 bytes into first integer, read next 4 into next integer. In this way you dont need to use strings to send integers. Just google on how to convert from `byte` to `Integer`.

Alternatively you should use a networking library like [Netty](http://netty.io/) which has a `ByteBuf` buffer class which already provides methods like `readInt`, `readLong` etc. And while you are at it, there are [game servers](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server/tree/netty4) already written in Netty that might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `DataInputStream`:

```
packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[PACKETSIZE], PACKETSIZE);

//Receive a packet (blocking)
socket.receive(packet);

DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(packet.getData(), packet.getOffset(), packet.getLength());

int x = din.readInt();
int y = din.readInt();
```